# Android firebase onStart and onStop explanation

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've just started with firebase in android and i can't understand some things in onStart and in onStop.

Why is it necessary to have this code on stop method? Why do we need to remove listener ?

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop: ");
    if(mAuthStateListener != null)
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}
```

And one more question what is the advantage of setting up mAuth listener in onStart method instead of onCreate ?

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ");
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}﻿
```

This is how they shoved in Firebase -> Authentication demo.

Comment: Can you link to the demo, need more context.

Comment: Demo is from Assistant window in android studio for firebase. Here is the pic : http://imgur.com/a/wkwKh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the need to remove listeners because the `mAuth` will keep of keeping track of all the listeners you added, in order to notify you when something happens.

When the activity stops you remove the listener from the list because well, the activity has stopped anyway, there is no need to listen for auth events when the activity is stopped, is there?

Why add the listener at `onStart` then?

Because according to the activity life cycle:

[image]

`onStart` and `onStop` correspond to each other, while `onCreate` and `onDestroy` correspond to each other.

If you add the listener in `onCreate` and remove at `onStop`, the listener will not be added back when the activity restarts, since `onCreate` is not called on restart. `onStart` *is*.

Comment: This was really good explanation. Just one more thing. The only reason why we delete listener is because it is not going to be used when app is stopped ? What would be if we didn't delete it? I guess nothing, am i right ?

Comment: Then there might be the possibility that a lot of memory is used, if you have a lot of listeners. Why not free the memory when the activity has stopped, right? @MiljanRakita

Comment: Yeah, yeah. You are right, thanks a lot for the answer. @Sweeper